# How to Stick elements on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I have a one page, scrolling site with 5 main sections that have title bars that span across the top of each respective section. I want each title bar to stick at the top (well, relative top-underneath the top sticky header) as you scroll down the section. I can get one to stick, but I am having trouble making it so that one sticks and then it goes away once the next section's title bar gets to the sticky point.

I can't figure out another way to bind the HTML or CSS with the jQuery if else statement to make this work. I was thinking I could try to make it work within each sections' id but I don't think there's like a "`withinId`" jQuery selector.

I'm posting the latest jQuery I attempted (*with just 2 out of the 5 variables I will need to make work here*). I know it's wrong but I'm seriously stuck. Any ideas here? Thanks a million.

(abbreviated) HTML:

```
<div id="welcome">
 <div class="title-bar">
  <p>WELCOME</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="global">
 <div class="title-bar">
  <p>GLOBAL ENGAGEMENT</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="community">
 <div class="title-bar">
  <p>COMMUNITY</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="resources">
 <div class="title-bar">
  <p>RESOURCES</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="horizon">
 <div class="title-bar">
  <p>ON THE HORIZON</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.title-bar {
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative; 
}

.title-bar.sticky {
     position: fixed;
     top: 111px;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 1040;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var welcomeTitle = $('#welcome .title-bar');
    var globalTitle = $('#global .title-bar');
    var communityTitle = $('#community .title-bar');
    var resourcesTitle = $('#resources .title-bar');
    var horizonTitle = $('#horizon .title-bar');

    var stickyOffset = $('#header').offset().top;

    if ($w.scrollTop() > stickyOffset + 225) {
        welcomeTitle.addClass('sticky');
        globalTitle.addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        welcomeTitle.removeClass('sticky');
        globalTitle.addClass('sticky');
    }

    if (welcomeTitle.hasClass('sticky') && globalTitle.hasClass('sticky')) {
        welcomeTitle.removeClass('sticky');
    } else {
        //
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean. May I can help you since I´ve been working on something I think similar. But I´ll need to understand better what is your goal. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://polarblau.github.io/stickySectionHeaders/ and see if that gives you some tips?

Comment: Here is the actual jquery they use : https://github.com/polarblau/stickySectionHeaders/blob/master/src/jquery.stickysectionheaders.js

Comment: ever heard of scrollspy ? check it out and key your css off user current position.

waypointsplugin looks better just because you wouldnt have to mess with removing the nav updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/xuxude/3/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Give your "pages" a `class="page"` and listen for their positions using JS's [`Element.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) on: DOM **Ready**, window **Load**, window **Scroll**

```js
$(function() { // DOM ready

  var $win  = $(window),
      $page = $(".page").each(function(){
        // Memorize their titles elements (performance boost)
        this._bar = $(this).find(".title-bar");
      });

  function fixpos() {
    $page.each(function(){
      var br = this.getBoundingClientRect();
      $(this._bar).toggleClass("sticky", br.top<0 && br.bottom>0);
    });
  }

  fixpos(); // on DOM ready
  $win.on("load scroll", fixpos); // and load + scroll

});
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
html, body{height:100%;}
body{margin:0;font:16px/1 sans-serif; color:#777;}


.page{
  position:relative;
  min-height:100vh;
}
.title-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.title-bar.sticky {
  position: fixed;
}

#welcome  {background:#5fc;}
#global   {background:#f5c;}
#community{background:#cf5;}
#resources{background:#fc5;}
#horizon  {background:#5cf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="welcome" class="page">
  <div class="title-bar">
    <h2>WELCOME</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="global" class="page">
  <div class="title-bar">
    <h2>GLOBAL ENGAGEMENT</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="community" class="page">
  <div class="title-bar">
    <h2>COMMUNITY</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="resources" class="page">
  <div class="title-bar">
    <h2>RESOURCES</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="horizon" class="page">
  <div class="title-bar">
    <h2>ON THE HORIZON</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Design-wise > add a padding-top to the first container element (inside your .page) to prevent content going underneath the title element (since it toggles from absolute/fixed positions).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working! The only thing I can't figure out is how to make it so the title bars are actually at top: 111px (instead of 0) because I have a sticky header (that is 111px tall) that I want the titles to stick to the bottom of. I tried putting + 111 to your jQuery in various places with no luck, and it doesn't work to add that to the sticky class either.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Waypoints plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make it a little easier on yourself by assigning each section a class and then add and remove the class from each section with jquery each function.

Try something like the following:

```
$(window).on( "scroll", function() {
    $( ".section" ).each(function() {
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top - 50 ) {
            $( this ).addClass("sticky");
        }else{
            $( this ).removeClass("sticky");
        }
    });
});
```

Then your css

```
.section{
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  border:1px solid #222;
  position:relative;
}
.section .title-bar{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
.section.sticky .title-bar {
  position:fixed;
}
```

And html

```
<div class="section">
     <div class="title-bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="section">
     <div class="title-bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="section">
     <div class="title-bar"></div>
</div>
```